# how to make a div go across the entire screen by the click of an icon?

Tags: jquery, html, css

HTML:

```
<div class="topleft hidden-xs">

    <div class="topleft-social-container">

        <section class="search1">

             <div class="search-dropdown hidden">   
                <input placeholder="search..." type="text"/> 
             </div>

             <div id="search-bar">

                <a href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook-square facebook"></i></a>
                <a href=""><i class="fa fa-twitter twitter"></i></a>
                <a href=""><i class="fa fa-soundcloud soundcloud"></i></a>
                <a href=""><i class="fa fa-youtube youtube"></i></a>
                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                <a href="#mailing-list" class="mailing-list-header">Mailing List</a> 

            </div>
     </section>

      </div>        
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden{

 display: none; 
 }
 input{
 border-radius: 5px;
 margin-top: 5px;
 width: 300px;
 height: 33px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 }
.search-dropdown{
 background-color: black;
 width: 100%; 
 border-radius: 5px;

 }
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#search-bar').click(function(){
        $(this).siblings('.search-dropdown').toggleClass('hidden');
         });
     });
```

this code comes out to look like this : 5 icons and when the user clicks on the magnyfying glass the search box appears above all of them to the left and wont stretch across the screen ( the div behind it) I made it black to help me give me a reference. It will only stretch as far as the end of the icons. Need help.

. this is what I want it to somewhat resemble : http://mic.com/ when you click on the magnifying it should pop open. The current iteration I have is in the correct placement, ( the search box ) just need a background div like the one from the url to work.

more css

```
 .topleft {
 background-color: transparent;
 margin: 1rem 0 0 0;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 font-size: 1.8rem;
 letter-spacing: .18rem;
 font-family: "Montserrat", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #ccc;
  }

  /* line 14, ../sass/_navigation.scss */
  .topleft a {
  color: #FF4247;
  }

  /* line 15, ../sass/_navigation.scss */
  .topleft a:hover {
  color: #FF4247;
  }

  /* line 19, ../sass/_navigation.scss */
  .topleft-social-container {
  padding: 1rem 0 0 3rem;
  }

  /* line 23, ../sass/_navigation.scss */
   .topleft i {
   font-size: 3.5rem;
   letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
   padding: 0.5rem;
   transition: .25s all;
   }

     /* line 30, ../sass/_navigation.scss */
    .topleft i:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
    transition: .25s all;
    }
```

Comment: You specifically have the input width set to 300px in your css rule.  If you want it to stretch the entire width, make it 100%.

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/ofwdgeq8/?

Comment: So I've done that before and the search bar (width 100%)  only stretches to the end of the icons because of the div the icons are in themselves. Any other way of setting the code, the jquery code doesn't work in html. I appreciate your help as well! @jme11

Comment: So i figured out how to make it go across the screen. but instead of making the icons be pushed down, how would I go about having the div be pushed up , so that it doesnt go in front of the other icons on the right side of the screen? @jme11